# C++ - Can I use extern and const at the same time with several files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The thing is that I am trying to have a global constant variable for all the `.h`and `.cpp` files, but when I do this I got the error:

```
array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

I do not understand this because `Z` is a constant. When I do this with just one file it works. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Number.h**

```
#include <iostream>

extern const int Z;
```

---

**a.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "Number.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    const int Z = 5;
    b Objeto1;
    c Objeto2;
    double H[Z][Z];
    Objeto1.Algo(H);
    Objeto2.Imprimir(H);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**b.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Number.h"

class b {
public:
    void Algo(double[Z][Z]);
};
```

---

**b.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"
#include "Number.h"
using namespace std;

void b::Algo(double H[Z][Z]) {
    for(int a = 0; a < Z; a++) {
        for(int b = 0; b < Z; b++) {
            H[a][b] = Z;
            cout << H[a][b] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**c.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Number.h"

class c {
public:
    void Imprimir(double H[Z][Z]);
};
```

---

**c.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "c.h"
#include "Number.h"

using namespace std;
void c::Imprimir(double V[Z][Z]) {
    cout << "dfs" << endl;
}
```

I know that the code does not make any sense, but I am just trying to understand how I could have a constant for all the files. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can have declaration that is both `extern` and `const`, one of the keywords specifies linkage, the other is a qualifier, and both can be combined. ***But*** you never *define* such a variable. Not in the global scope anyway.

Comment: Then there's the problem that `const` variables doesn't have to be compile-time constant variables, which are needed for array sizes. You should probably use [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) instead.

Comment: The error message is misleading, it should say "Z is not an **integer constant expression**". The value of a `const`-qualified variable may or may not be a *constant expression*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of

```
extern const int Z;
```

is perfectly fine. However, you can't use `Z` to define an array. Hence, use of `Z` in the following line, and similar other lines, is incorrect.

```
class b{
public:
        void Algo(double[Z][Z]);

};
```

The size of arrays must be known at compiler time. With the `extern` declaration you have provided, that is not true.

The use of `extern const` is justified only when you wish to define the value at run time and expect the value to not change until the program ends.

If you simply wish to use it as a token for defining arrays, remove the `extern` and set its value also. Use:

```
const int Z = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But for example if I want to define the const for all the file, what I have to do? because if I remove the extern, I got the error that I am redefining the constant

Comment: @Mohammet, it will be better if you post another question, with a suitable [mcve], that demonstrates the problem.